# How can I reference my list name as a string to use it as a file name eg. png(paste0(list, ".png"))?

Tags: r, export

I'm using RStudio and none of my packages should affect this, I'm new to coding so this might be very basic.

Referencing my list in this simple for-loop causes the name of the exported .png file to be the first item in the list where I would want it to just be "MG" instead.

```
AC <- list("gene_a", "gene_b", ...etc)
MG <- list("gene_a", "gene_b", ...etc)

CellTypes <- list(MG, BC, OFFBC, ONBC, Cones, GabaAC, GlyAC, HC, Microglia, Oligo, Pericytes, 
                      Progenitors , RGC, RPE, V_E, Astrocytes, Rods)


for(c in CellTypes){
  for(g in c){
    png(paste0(c, ".png"))
    plot(FeaturePlot(object = object, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE,  features = g))
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

How can convert the list name (c in png(paste0(c, ".png"))) so my exported .png would be "MG" or "AC" for each of the genes in the MG or AC list?

Currently I end up with the .png named as the first item in the list and it breaks the iteration of each item in the eg. MG list.

Apologies if this is strangely worded, very new to coding.

Comment: Wouldn't you end up trying to write multiple files with the same name? Like AC.png, AC.png, etc. for every gene in AC list?

Comment: That's exactly the goal! I'm trying a roundabout way to create a gif for each gene in the AC list, each gene in the MC list and about 15 more cell types; there's about 30 genes in each gene list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(c in CellTypes){
  for(g in c){
    nm = deparse(substitute(paste0(c, "_", g)) 
    png(paste0(nm, ".png"))
    plot(FeaturePlot(object = object, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE,  features = g))
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey appreciate the answer but this didn't work either. What's also interesting is that I have a list of lists essentially, and I'm trying to run the featureplot and export it for each of the contents within the sub-list (MG), then move on to the second list within the CellType list (AC) and have the featureplot for each of the items in that list exported. Not only is the naming convention not working, but the loop seems to abruptly and prematurely terminate. Seems to have something to do with the file name line but I can't figure it out.